# How to use IntelliSense to debug abstract classes in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, design-patterns, abstract-class, intellisense

I am trying to understand a codebase that uses software design patterns heavily. Meaning, almost all input parameters are abstract factories of abstract classes. I want to look at the existing implementation to properly decide whether I should implement the abstract classes from scratch or extend the concrete implementation classes, as well as parsing the shapes of the input arrays. When I `Ctrl + click` a statement in the code, I can only see empty unimplemented methods of the abstract class. I then have to manually search for the relevant method definitions. It is taking me forever to look up the concrete implementations of the abstract classes. Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: To give a concrete example, in PyCharm, between the line number and the function definition, there is a blue dot with an arrow that shows all the implementations that override a certain method.